# How to fix stripped screw holes for dishwasher rack rails?

Tags: screws, dishwasher

Four years ago, I installed a new [GE plastic interior dishwasher, model GDF630PGMWW](https://www.geappliances.com/appliance/GE-ENERGY-STAR-Front-Control-with-Plastic-Interior-Dishwasher-with-Sanitize-Cycle-Dry-Boost-GDF630PGMWW), in my kitchen. For the last year or two, the screws that attach the upper rack rails to the wall have occasionally become loose. I have tightened them several times, but now they are so loose that none of them can be tightened. We can keep the rails in place only by handling the upper rack very gently and pulling it out halfway.

The screw holes seem to be stripped. They seem to be made of the same plastic material of which the walls are made.

I haven't tried anything because I don't want to wreck the holes even further without getting some expert advice. I really don't want to get a new dishwasher just for this; it's only four years old and does a good job of washing dishes.

How can I remedy this situation? Fill the holes with some product? Get bigger screws? Something else?

[image: left rail with loose screws]

[image: right rail with loose screws]

Comment: There's always the sloppy solution of installing larger screws to cut new threads...

Answer (score 1):

Pull the dishwasher out and confirm that you can see the tips of the screws from the outside. Assuming that you can --

- Replace the sheet metal screws with stainless machine screws of an
  appropriate diameter and length.
- Install Nylock or similar non-loosening nuts onto the machine screws
  from the outside. You may need a washer, depending on what the
  bearing surface looks like.

Comment: Another idea may be to try the "toothpick" trick—obviously using plastic toothpicks instead of wood ones!

Comment: Two thumbs up for pulling out the dishwasher.  I would not do *anything* without knowing exactly what you are screwing into.  No toothpicks, no larger screws, no tricks. See what's on the other side of the wall, what's wrong with it, and proceed from there.  And having done that, a nut and bolt sounds easier than any kind of thread repair.

Comment: If I see tips of screws sticking out on the outside of an appliance, I would have second thoughts.

Comment: @crip659 The built-in dishwashers that I've worked on have no outer shell like you would see on a clothes washer. The (inner / only) shell is typically wrapped in insulation that you can move aside to see fasteners coming through. The point of checking to see the tips of the screws is just to confirm accessibility, because if not accessible, a machine screw and nut is not a suitable solution.

Comment: I might try this, but I'm curious about the screws poking through the outside. If that were the case, wouldn't there be water leaking through?

Comment: @GarySheppard The wheelie bits may include a water seal; it's hard to know from your photos. Or the screws could be in blind holes with the tips not actually visible. If that's the case, you would see little protuberances on the outside like the eraser end of a fat pencil. If that's what you have, you could drill through the tip from the inside or cut off the tip from the outside. A small O-ring under the head of the machine screw would guarantee that it remains water-tight.

Answer (score 0):

Hot glue might hold up, but with the heat of the water, not sure.  Ideally, some JBWeld marine epoxy, followed by tapping new holes.

Comment: Hot glue melting temperature ranges from about 250-375ºF (I think there are different types) which should be well below the temperature inside a dishwasher (140-170ºF).  I suppose it's possible the glue may soften—but not melt—at those temperatures.  But it's certainly worth a try!  What has the OP got to lose, right?

Comment: Hot glue is really quite temperature sensitive. It will soften, the question is whether it's enough to cause a problem. It also goes fairly brittle not far below room temperature (it's not very useful for things on bikes for this reason) so if the dishwasher fills with cold water and starts circulating it before heating, as mine does, you end up with quite a bit of thermal cycling. I've had success with epoxy (Araldite) inside a dishwasher and fully cured epoxy should be OK around things that touch food